# Google Webrtc App shuts down without any notice

Tags: android, webrtc

I followed the example code from [the offical Google Webrtc for android](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/master/examples). But my app shuts up (not crash) without any notice after playing the video from my mobile camera for a short moment. I checked both my codes against the example codes for numerous times but still cannot find any possible explanation.

Does anyone has any clue?

Comment: Can you share code samples and do you have any relevant log files?

Comment: sorry, I dont have.

Comment: Can you include a link to the google example code you mention?

Comment: https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/master/examples